# How to expose SSH port publicly from a machine inside VPN?

Tags: ssh, vpn

Suppose I have a machine A that is logged into a VPN.
How can I expose this machine A to the Internet such that I can connect to this machine (and get inside the VPN) using just SSH from another machine B?
Note that there are no other machines inside the VPN that expose an SSH port publicly.

Apologies if this has been asked before, I just don't know what to look for and would be greatful if you point to a post asking exactly this question.

Comment: No need to look for exactly this question, it's just like setting up an SSH server on any other computer. The VPN has nothing to do with it.

Comment: This entirely depends if the VPN is accessible to the internet. It also depends if Machine B can connect to the same VPN.

Comment: @mtak: It really does; if the VPN client sets up a default route, then even connections coming from the "outside" (e.g. directly via eth0) will result in the reply packets going via the VPN instead. The OS needs source-based routing for this to work properly.

Comment: Probably good to add that to your question, it's not exactly a bog-standard setup ;). Is it an option for you to ditch the default route?